# Can I get overall click count for entire SP2013 farm?

Tags: powershell, statistics

We are using SP2013 on-premise standard. There are over 50 site collections. By checking each site collection's popularity trend we can see each site collection's click count.

However it is too time consuming to download the reports for over 50 site collection. Is there any existing function or Powershell script can query the summary for entire farm? If not possible, can I query all site collections' figure by PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetRollupAnalyticsItemData` method of `SearchServiceApplication` might help:

```
$site = Get-SPSite "{SiteUrl}"   
$date = Get-Date "2016-03-07"
$a = (Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication).GetRollupAnalyticsItemData(1, [System.Guid]::Empty, $site.ID, [System.Guid]::Empty)
$a.GetHitCountForDay($date)
```

This snippet returns **view count** (first argument of `GetRollupAnalyticsItemData` is [`1`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.server.search.analytics.standardeventtypeid.aspx)) for **one day** (`GetHitCountForDay`). There are [other methods and properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.analytics.analyticsitemdata_members.aspx)  available.

Modify it to get whatever data you need and pipe `Get-SPSite -limit all` to it. `GetRollupAnalyticsItemData` can also get an argument of `GUID` type with and ID of particular SPWeb inside SPSite.

---

Or we can automate analytic reports generation (those excel-files) for each site collection, and then parse them. Good places to start: http://spandps.com/2015/05/30/automating-sharepoint-2013-usage-reports/ and https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/25/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2/